# How to get unique rows by one column but sort by the second

Tags: postgresql

There is an example request in which there are several joins.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON(a.id_1) 1, a.name, b.task, c.created_at
FROM a
INNER JOIN b ON a.id_2 = b.id
INNER JOIN c ON a.ID_2 = c.id
WHERE a.deleted_at IS NULL
ORDER BY a.id_1 desc
```

In this case, the query will work, sorting by unique values ​​of `id_1` will take place. But I need to sort by the column `a.name`. In this case, postresql will swear with the words `ERROR: SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions`.

The following query can serve as a solution to the problem:

```
SELECT * 
FROM(
    SELECT DISTINCT ON(a.id_1) a.name, b.task, c.created_at
    FROM a
    INNER JOIN b ON a.id_2 = b.id
    INNER JOIN c ON a.ID_2 = c.id
    WHERE a.deleted_at IS NULL
)
ORDER_BY a.name desc
```

But in reality the database is very large and such a query is not optimal. Are there other ways to sort by the selected column while keeping one uniqueness?

Comment: You can sort by as many columns as you want, as long as you first sort by the columns in the `DISTINCT ON` expression. So your first query can be `ORDER BY a.id_1, 1, a.name` (note, 1 = column 1 since i see no name on it, am addressing it numerically). If you want to ONLY sort by name desc, then I don't see how to do it without a subquery.

Comment: @404, sorry i forgot to remove column 1. Wouldn't the sort then happen on two columns? I need to do sorting strictly by one column

Comment: Can you add the failing query to the question?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, In this question, I have shown everything that is

Comment: You show a query and say "in this case, the query will work". Then you say "But I need to sort by the column a.name. In this case, postresql will swear with the words ...". So you somehow modify the query so that it causes an error, but we don't know exactly what you did. I need to see the failing query to be able to tell you what you did wrong.